# Ajax loading progress with run time data

Tags: android, ajax, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am working on phonegap project. I am using ajax request calls and it is working fine. But I want to display the dynamic data on loading ajax requests.Sample image shown below. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: do u have multiple ajax requests and each request is downloading a file ?

Comment: Thanks for asking.Yes I have multiple ajax requests